# Drag and Drop window in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to drag an UIButton to my View, but the view with the Drag and Drop Function isn't there, where it should be?

I'm a absolutely beginner.
I have the Xcode version 10.1 beta 2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to place a button in your View Controller, simply tap the top icon that looks like an old iPhone button and drag in the button:

[image]

---

You can also use keyboard shortcuts:

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to **show** the `Object Library`, or use <kbd>Option</kbd> with the shortcut to **open** the `Object Library`.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 10 they have been moved, click on the first top rounded button (near the `show standard editor`) of your picture or use the shortcut ⇧+⌘+L to open the library and ⇧+⌘+M to open the media.

[image]